# Ploting two controls in one datagridview cell in windows application?

Tags: c#, .net

On the datagridview cellclick event i have ploted two controls,one is a combobox that displays weekdays and 
other is a datetimepicker control.
By default both the controls are left aligned hence i am not able to view the date inside datetimepicker control.
Hence i changed the property of datetimepicker control to:

```
 dtPickerForFolder.DropDownAlign = LeftRightAlignment.Right;
```

But the problem is if i set this property i am able to see the date inside datetimepicker control in this format:
PM02:57:12.That is in a reverse format.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: What does ploted mean? I don't think that's an actual word.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You don't have to appologise, but would you mind trying to explain what you mean by it? What are you doing with the two controls?

Comment: I would probably try to add the two controls to a FlowLayoutPanel (as Nikolay suggested) and add *that* panel in the place you are adding the two controls now, and skip the DropDownAlign property. You can also mess around with Anchor and Width to see what happens with your controls.

Comment: I am almost close to the solution but the flowLayoutPanel is getting displayed outside of the datagridview. Instead it should be inside the cell.

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick.I got my problem solved with the help of flowLayoutPanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not very good in WinForms, but probably you should add two controls in some container. In WPF it could be StackPanel or something. I think WinForms has something similar

Comment: I am not having problem plotting the controls.The problem is occurring in the alignment of date in datetimepicker.

Comment: Got it. Date in control is printed according to localization/globalization settings. Can it be your case? Can you also add a screenshot please, because i am not sure, that i undersood your correctly

Comment: I cant add screenshot as my reputation points are less than 10.